# Cannot send AT commands in minicom

Tags: serial-port, arduino, minicom

I am trying to use `minicom` to communicate with an ESP8266 Wifi chip using AT commands. I log into `minicom` and I type command "AT". The normal answer of the chip would be to send "OK" back to `minicom`. However, after typing "AT", once I type "Enter" the cursor goes back to the beginning of the line and nothing happens. It is as though the command had not been sent.

I log into `minicom` with

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200
```

In the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, I am able to communicate with the chip by setting baud = 115200 and "Both NL & CR". When sending command "AT", the chip sends back answer "OK". I am trying to reproduce the same in `minicom`.

Any idea why the command doesn't get sent ?

**Update**

I saw in many `minicom` tutorials that command prompt `cmd>` should appear. Yet it does not appear on my screen. Maybe this is an indication that `minicom` is only in "listening" mode, and not in "waiting for command from the user" mode ?

Comment: The 'Update (Solved !)' section should really be submitted as an answer - you are allowed and in fact encouraged to answer your own questions on stack exchange.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Moving the OP answer to an actual answer:</sub>

Ok so the trick seems to be to type a command in [`minicom`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom) ([here the man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/minicom.1.html)), then type <kbd>Enter</kbd>, **then press <kbd>CTRL + J</kbd>**.

I found the following tip (related to the same issue in utility `screen`) in [this ESP8266 quick start guide](https://www.mpja.com/download/esp8266%20wifi%20module%20quick%20start%20guide%20v%201.0.4.pdf) ([here the datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf)):

> Unfortunately the updated firmware versions require
>   Carriage-Return-and-New-Line line endings and there appears to be no
>   way to configure `screen` to send both with one key press. Instead, you
>   need to press   or  Ctrl-M then follow that with Ctrl-J.

In other words, the ESP8266 expects to see [CR-NL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) after each command. When typing "Enter" in the `minicom` window, it sends character Carriage-Return (CR). This is why my cursor goes back to the beginning of the line. Then by typing Ctrl-J, it sends the New-Line (NL, AKA [LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) character. The cursor moves to the next line and the ESP8622 understands the instruction, thus sending back "OK" to `minicom`.

I still do not see the `cmd>` prompt in `minicom`, but this is not an issue... Maybe this prompt does not appear in all versions of `minicom` (I am using 2.7).